# Getting a Foursquare's tweet geoLocation

Tags: twitter, foursquare, twitter4j

What would be the easiest way to extract the Lat and Long fields of a 'check-in' location being tweeted? When viewing tweets through a client and "expanding" them the location is shown even though the tweet does not always contain the geoLocation properties. I would like to achieve the same result (Is a Foursquare API account needed for that?)
I am using Twitter4j by the way.
Thanks for the help,
Boris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the information is not in the geoLocation property, you will need to call the foursquare API (https://developer.foursquare.com) to retrieve the lat/lng for the venue the user checked in to. You may want to look at similar questions that have been asked in the past for more details, like: [How can I get the position (lat, lon) of a foursquare checkin posted on twitter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8780866/how-can-i-get-the-position-lat-lon-of-a-foursquare-checkin-posted-on-twitter/8807791#8807791)